# Rails help with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, devise, associations

Hey I was trying to make an association in devise so a user can just have a link to his association (like he can just click new post and he can make it) but i cant make it in devise like regular rails, it seems really common but no one seems able to help me (or they dont know what im talking about), I tried manually making come controllers and views but i get a problem (500 internal server error) heres my log file
https://github.com/Kevin-Mohamed/mygit
any other information needed let me know

Comment: I can see that you are trying to access 'devise/pictures/new.html.erb' and getting a syntax error in 'app/views/devise/pictures/_form.html.erb'. Are those pages that came with devise or ones you created yourself? If you could clarify your question a bit it would help as well.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson I made them myself (the devise folder as well as a folder in controllers for devise)

Comment: @mike-williamson I made them myself (the devise folder as well as a folder in controllers for devise) . What I mean in the question is that I don't know how do something like say if you were making youtube and a user wanted to upload a video, how would i make the youtube account link to the upload page. (in this case, making a user be able to upload a picture from a page he can access, so maybe I'm just confused about how to do the link_to for devise so only a user can access the upload the picture)

Comment: What is this? `form_for([:devise, @picture]`

Comment: @jesse-wolgamott I imitated the process from here https://github.com/thauanz/Photos-Gallery mainly substituting gallery for picture as well as admin for devise. I'm really not sure how to accomplish associatons in devise, if you could guide me through it would be helpful, I don't know what exactly form_for([:devise, @picture] means either, I think it lets you acces s the picture controller in controller/devise/picture_controller.rb

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is off the top of my head, so YMMV. There's plenty of ways to go around this, but here's one way... Don't try to get devise to do more than it should.

```
class User
  #devise links go here
  has_many :pictures
end

class Picture
  belongs_to :user
end

#routes
namespace :my do
  resources :pictures
end

class ApplicationController
  # current_user gets set here by devise
end

class PicturesController
  def create
    @picture = current_user.pictures.build(params[:picture])
  end
end

#In your view you'd have the following, which would post to /my/pictures

=form_for(my_pictures_path(@picture)) do |f|
  ... etc
```

Comment: thanks, it looks helpful, I've given up on it for right now and I'm sort of deep into another part of the application, but I'll try this later